# How can I obtain result execution Sftp with php exec shell from crontab?

Tags: php, shell, cron, sftp, shell-exec

When I execute the script from terminal, it prints result sftp.
If the php script is executed from cron it not prints nothing, $result is empty.

Crontab:

```
23 12 * * *  php script.php >> /tmp/logs.log
```

The script:

```
<?php
$command = 'lftp -u user,Password sftp://domain.com -e "set ftp:passive-mode off; set ftp:auto-passive-mode on; put -O /path/tests toTransfer/file.zip; bye;"';
$result = shell_exec($command);
echo $result;
if ($result) echo "uploaded";
else echo "Not uploaded";
?>
```

Comment: Where are you expecting the output to be echoed to?
By default output from a cron job is emailed to the account running the cron daemon - see *man cron* for details.

Comment: I want obtain result execution to know if the file is uploaded successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the `cron` is running under a different account than the one you use in a shell.

Your script likely relies on your account environment (like a file with known host keys). The cron account does not have that, so the `lftp` fails.

It's likely that the `lftp` prints some error on an error output. But you are collecting a standard output only.

Try to start with a plain shell script and redirect both stdout and stderr to the log file:

```
lftp -u user,Password sftp://domain.com 2>&1 > /tmp/log.log
```

---

Note that you are using SFTP. So it does not make sense to set FTP-specific options of `lftp`, like `ftp:passive-mode` (there's no passive mode in SFTP).